# How to retrieve values from a numeric matrix using the which() function in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a numeric matrix from which I want to retrieve the index given specific values.
I am trying the `which()` function to find values in the matrix.

The problem is that some values are found and some are not.

My matrix is as follows:

```
x_lat <- as.double(seq(48.0  ,60.0,  by=0.1))
y_long <- as.double(seq(-10.0 ,2.0,   by=0.1))
xv <- as.double(rep(x_lat,each = 121))
yv <- as.double(rep(y_long, 121))

vMatrix <- as.matrix(cbind(xv,yv))
```

If I want to retrieve the indices where the value -2.3 is TRUE the function returns correctly a  vector with the indices where -2.3 appears.

```
 xx<- which(vMatrix==-2.3,arr.ind=TRUE)

> xx
  [1]    78   199   320   441   562   683   804   925  1046  1167  1288  1409  1530  1651  1772  1893  2014  2135  2256  2377  2498
 [22]  2619  2740  2861  2982  3103  3224  3345  3466  3587  3708  3829  3950  4071  4192  4313  4434  4555  4676  4797  4918  5039
 [43]  5160  5281  5402  5523  5644  5765  5886  6007  6128  6249  6370  6491  6612  6733  6854  6975  7096  7217  7338  7459  7580
 [64]  7701  7822  7943  8064  8185  8306  8427  8548  8669  8790  8911  9032  9153  9274  9395  9516  9637  9758  9879 10000 10121
 [85] 10242 10363 10484 10605 10726 10847 10968 11089 11210 11331 11452 11573 11694 11815 11936 12057 12178 12299 12420 12541 12662
[106] 12783 12904 13025 13146 13267 13388 13509 13630 13751 13872 13993 14114 14235 14356 14477 14598
```

But for some numbers (that appear in the matrix) the function does not work, e.g.,

```
 xx<- which(vMatrix==-2.2,arr.ind=TRUE)

> xx
integer(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating point numbers can be misleading. Two such numbers are usually not "equal", even though the console may display the same output. The machine only has a certain accuracy with which it can represent the numbers.

Here's a simple example:

```
a <- 0.15 - 1/8 
b <- 0.025
> a
[1] 0.025
> b
[1] 0.025
```

However, if we compare these numbers with "==", we obtain:

```
> a==b
[1] FALSE
```

That is because there are differences resulting from the floating point arithmetic which are beyond the machine's accuracy:

```
> a-b
[1] -6.938894e-18
```

Probably you can resolve the issue by simply rounding the numbers in the matrix to the necessary amount of relevant digits, like, e.g.,

```
xx<- which(round(vMatrix,3)==-2.2,arr.ind=TRUE)
```

Comment: Values on the matrix have just one decimal so I didn't think it made sense rounding them to a higher number of decimals.  I see now how it makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Using `round` is not a very good way of comparing numbers with floating point tolerance. `all.equal` implements a better way. More details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9508558/1968

Comment: @KonradRudolph thanks for the great reference..In this case I would need to implement `all.equal()` using `which()` in a different manner, but that is another problem

Comment: turns out I can loop through the matrix using `all.equal` and `which()`, tip was a  the end of the reference... thus.. `which(mapply(function(x, y) {isTRUE(all.equal(x, y))}, round(vMatrix[,2],3), -2.2), arr.ind=TRUE)` works as well